# Retrieving Microsoft OAuth2 token configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm using Microsoft as an OAuth2 provider, and would like to validate the JWT token in my ASP.NET application. I'm getting an odd error where the initial request to .well-known/openid-configuration fails, but subsequent requests succeed - at least until the DNS re-resolves. The code that's falling over is:

```
  using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
  using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
  using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
  using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;       


        string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config;
        ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
```

This above throws an exception

> Unable to connect to the remote server: 
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.126.1.128:443

The IP address changes periodically, but always belongs to Microsoft. The first call to a new IP address always gets this response. I've checked our firewall settings and logs, and it doesn't look like it's the problem.

Any ideas?